# How to get the value of the selected check-box value in XUl JavaScript

Tags: javascript, checkbox, xul, alert

This is my check-box and it's created dynamically by getting the value of the XUL tree.

```
var yyahoo = tree.view.getCellText(i, tree.columns.getNamedColumn("yahoo")); 

  var existing  = document.getElementById('box');
  var checkbox   = document.createElement('checkbox');
  capt.appendChild(checkbox);
  checkbox.setAttribute('label', yyahoo);
  checkbox.setAttribute("checked", "false")
  checkbox.setAttribute('style', 'color: green;');
```

Like this I have dynamically created many check-boxes in my XUL file.

When I checked Mozilla website, it is explained that, i have to use hasAttribute() to get the value of the selected check-box, which is confusing to me.

Please help me to get the value of the selected check-box.

This is the button to get the values on-click.

```
<row><button label="get" oncommand="get();"/></row>
```

This is function: This function is not working 'cause something is missing in my function.

```
function get()
{
// check that the attribute exists before setting a value
var d = document.getElementById("box");
if (d.hasAttribute("checkbox")) {
 alert(d);
}

}
```

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `checkbox` is a *child* of the element with ID `box`, not an attribute. Try something like this:

```
function get() {
    // check that the attribute exists before setting a value
    var table = document.getElementById("box"); 
    var cells = table.getElementsByTagName("checkbox"); 
    for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) { 
        var cell = cells[i];
        if(cell.checked) {
            alert(cell.getAttribute("label"));
            // or cell.label
        }
     }
}
```

The `checked` property tells you whether the checkbox is currently selected or not. `hasAttribute('checked')` tells you whether the attribute was set or not. Maybe you have to use both, I don't know.

<del>Apparently, the [`checkbox` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/checkbox) element has no attribute `value`, so I don't know which value you are talking about.</del>

Comment: In my xul file, my check-box has value from the variable 'yyahoo ' in my question. When i select the check-box and click the button to get the value.

Comment: That seems to be the `label`, not the value. You can get it via `checkbox.label` or `checkbox.getAttribute('label')`.

Comment: You are right, it's a label but this label has value which is replaced with the value of my XUL tree .

Comment: I'm trying like this: function get() {
// check the alignment on a number of cells in a table.
var table = document.getElementById("box");
var cells = table.getElementsByTagName("checkbox");
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    var status = cells[i].getAttribute("label");
    alert(status );
}
} This function gives me value of the check-box even when it's not selected.

Comment: Yes, because you are not testing whether the checkbox is checked or not. Add an `if` clause: `if(cells[i].checked) { alert(status); }`;

Comment: it works fine. Please update your answer with this function. Thanks for your support.